# Mongoose can't access to data with findOne or find method

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to access `amount`. I can see datas :

Schema :

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    investors : {
        id        : String, 
        amount     : Number,
        user_id      : String,
        inv_profit : Number
    }

});
```

Command

```
invs2.findOne({}, function(err, data){

        console.log(data)
})
```

Output :

```
{ _id: 54159a1c291df572283fa4de,
  investors: 
   [ { inv_profit: 0,
       user_id: 'userID',
       amount: 1.2,
       id: '1410701852660' },
     { inv_profit: 0,
       user_id: 'userID',
       amount: 1.2,
       id: '1410701858752' } ] }
```

---

```
invs2.findOne({}, function(err, data){

        console.log(data.investors)
})
```

Output:

```
[ { id: '1410701852660',
    amount: 1.2,
    user_id: 'userID',
    inv_profit: 0 },
  { id: '1410701858752',
    amount: 1.2,
    user_id: 'userID',
    inv_profit: 0 } ]
```

---

But when I trying to access `data.investors[0].amount` I'm getting `undefined`?

Even `data.investors.length` is returning `undefined`.

There is only one entry in `invs2` collection.

Comment: Yes I've added schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`investors` should be defined as an array in your schema if it's an array of sub-docs:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    investors : [{
        id        : String, 
        amount     : Number,
        user_id      : String,
        inv_profit : Number
    }]
});
```